# How to give all members in a server a role?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

How do i add a role to everyone in a discord server? discord.js

I've tried this:

````
if (!role) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, role not found`)

message.guild.members.forEach(member => member.addRole(role))```
````

Comment: Adding a role to everyone in the server is a bad design - firstly, roles should bypass most of the default security features that Discord provides to servers. Also, if your server has upwards of 50 members, you will see yourself hitting ratelimits pretty damn quickly with an iteration loop, and if you continue, it is likely that you will be api banned

Answer (score 0):

for discord.js v12, you should try that:

```
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => member.roles.add(role))
```

If you could not do it again, than maybe you have no rights to use `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent. In order to enable it, you should go to developer page and select your bot and enable `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent. [Here](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056426994) is the documentation

Comment: while this is correct it provides no way to postpone the api calls if ratelimits are hit
this will become very problematic if you want to add a role to say, 20k members as the general guideline for PATCH MEMBER is 10/10s and will likely result in an API ban if you continue

Comment: Incorrect! But, I did figure it out, it's actually ```role.id```, not role edit: I WAS WRONG

Comment: actually, it only does two people.

Comment: liquidhope, as you were saying, how do i do such a thing? (delay)

Comment: @liquidhope how do i do that?

Comment: @trashcan91234712 you can implement some sort of queue checker with `setInterval()`, though, again, 10 members every 10 seconds ---> 20k members would take approximately 5 hours if you want to keep your ratelimits clean.
All i'm saying is that you should be wary of scalability